# Allow native C++ components to raise CLR Asynchronous events

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I need in my Native code to raise an asynchronous event to C#,I have used as bridge CLI ,actually I have gone though sending a pointer to function from C++/CLI but it did not work properly?
I need to know:1-What is wrong? 2-how can make it asynchronous event to not block the processing?
I need in this example to raise an event each time I reach 1000,here is my code 
Count.h

```
typedef void pointertofunc(bool IsOverFlowOccured);
typedef pointertofunc *pointertofuncdelegate;
class count
{

public:
    void startCounting(pointertofuncdelegate);
    count();
    ~count();
};
```

Count.cpp

```
void count::startCounting(pointertofuncdelegate)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        //printf("%d \n", i);
        if (i == 1000)
        {
            pointertofuncdelegate(true);
            printf("%d \n", i);
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**CLR**(.h file)

```
public delegate void manageddelegate(bool isworkflowoccured);
ref class CounterRaiseAsynchronousEvent
{
public:
    event manageddelegate^ managedEventHandler;
    CounterRaiseAsynchronousEvent();
    void initialize();
    void raiseEvent(bool eoverFlow);

private:
    count* wrapperObject;
};
```

**CLR**(.cpp file)

```
    void CounterRaiseAsynchronousEvent::initialize()
{
    //Create a new delegate and point it to the member function
    manageddelegate^ prDel = gcnew manageddelegate(this, &CounterRaiseAsynchronousEvent::raiseEvent);
    GCHandle gch = GCHandle::Alloc(prDel);
    //Convert the delegate to a function pointer
    IntPtr ip = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(prDel);
    //... and cast it to the appropriate type
    pointertofuncdelegate fp = static_cast<pointertofuncdelegate>(ip.ToPointer());
    //set the native function pointer on the native class
    wrapperObject->startCounting(fp);
}
void CounterRaiseAsynchronousEvent::raiseEvent(bool isOverflowOccurred)
{
    //Do any thing
}
```

Comment: Your delegate declaration does not match the function pointer type, the calling convention is wrong.  You need to apply the `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]` attribute.

Comment: @HansPassant I did not get ur point

Comment: "Ur" is an ancient city in Mesopotamia.

Comment: @tulipe, what Hans meant is: `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)] public delegate void manageddelegate(bool isworkflowoccured);`

Answer (score -1):

It's not usually a good idea for the event source to implement an asynchronous handling model -- that forces the client code to be multi-threaded and do synchronization, and causes complications when different components have chosen different models.

Instead, call events synchronously, and let the subscriber pend the callback and return immediately.  This is compatible with any asynchronous model the client code prefers, such as native `PostMessage` or `Control.BeginInvoke` or TPL (async/await) or worker threadpool.